# How to merge an Android application with a library

Tags: android, merge, android-library

My question is: How can I merge an Android app with a library? I have only one application left which refers to this library so I want to combine them and get rid of that library.

Are there any "tools" which I could use? Or is possible to merge them "manually" anyway?

The Android Developers Site and Google couldn't help me and my various attempts to fix it by hand failed as well so I'm thankful for any advice or hint.

Comment: Why do you actually want to merge the library project to the Android application project ? Library projects are good since it can be reused across multiple applications.

Comment: It's because we have just one android app and there won't be another one in future either

Answer (score 0):

Create a `jar` of this library and put it inside the `libs/` folder of your application

Answer (score 0):

see if u want create library right click that project->properties->android and tick is library and click apply button. then in your main android app right click project=>properties->android->add and select that library project and goto java build path goto projects and add library project->ok. Now library project is merged with your project.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on project.Select properties->Android.In that go to "Library" section and click on "Add".It will show you the list of libraries available.Select the one you want to merge.